# Get the value of the groupings of the selected dropdown jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown wherein I wanted to get the value of the groupings and set the value in the textfield whenever any change is made. However my code below is not working:

```html
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
  <option value="1" grouping="valueiwant">first</option>
  <option value="2" grouping="valueiwantsecond">four</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectsample').change(function() {
      var val = $('#selectsample').val();
      $("#txt1").val(val); // this is my textfield id=txt1
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the value of select box and then find correct option matching the value. read attribute from option will give grouping value

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#selectsample').change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val(); // replace $(this) which refer to select box for which change event occurred
      //var $option= $(this).find('option:selected'); -- you can use this option too
      var $option= $(this).find('option[value=' + val + ']');
      $("#txt1").val($option.attr('grouping'));// this is my textfield id=txt1
    }).change();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
    <option value="1" grouping="valueiwant"  >first</option>
    <option value="2" grouping="valueiwantsecond"  >four</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='txt1'>
```

Comment: The issue is that the OP is attempting to read the `grouping` attribute.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for pointing out. I read it wrongly, now i have corrected my answer

Comment: The Value I wanted to get is the grouping value like valueiwant to display in the field

Comment: `option:selected` is a much more elegant method of getting the chosen `option`

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that putting non-standard attributes on an HTML element is invalid, which can lead to rendering or JS problems. If you want to store custom data in an element, use a `data` attribute.

To read the value back out, you need to retrieve the selected `option` from the `select` first. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectsample').change(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var val = $select.val();
    var grouping = $select.find('option:selected').data('grouping');

    $('#value').val(val);
    $('#grouping').val(grouping);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
  <option value="1" data-grouping="value-i-want">first</option>
  <option value="2" data-grouping="value-i-want-second">four</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="value" />
<input type="text" id="grouping" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>



    <select id="selectsample" name="samp">
        <option value="1" grouping="valueiwant">first</option>
        <option value="2" grouping="valueiwantsecond">four</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="" />

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#selectsample').change(function () {
                var val = $('#selectsample').val();

                $("#txt1").val(val); // this is my textfield id=txt1
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> **Buddy your code is working fine.**

Just make sure your ID for text field is correct.In your case its should be something like this

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" value=""/>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
        <option value="1" grouping="valueiwant"  >first</option>
        <option value="2" grouping="valueiwantsecond"  >four</option>
</select>
```

and your Jquery is working fine too

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#selectsample').change(function(){
      var val = $('#selectsample').val();

      $("#txt1").val(val);// this is my textfield id=txt1
    });
  });
```

Comment: The issue is that the OP is attempting to read the `grouping` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with value you're referring to the text inside the options right?!

Here's the code:

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#selectsample').change(function() {
      var val = jQuery('#selectsample option:selected').text();
      jQuery("#txt1").val(val);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectsample" name="samp">
  <option value="1" grouping="valueiwant">first</option>
  <option value="2" grouping="valueiwantsecond">four</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
```